# JSON use child object in serializer

Tags: java, json

volks!
I have problem with JSON serialize
For example, I have two classes

> ```
> public class Site {
> private String eID;
> private Integer sID;
>
> public Site(String eID, Integer sID){
>     this.sID = sID;
>     this.eID = eID;
> }
>
> public String getEID(){
>     return eID;
> }
>
> public Integer getSID(){
>     return sID;
> } }
> ```

and class which includes object of previous type. For example, something like

```
public class Address{
private BigInteger addrID;
private ICOMSSitePOJO site;

public AddressUnitPOJO(BigInteger addrID, Site site){
    this.addrID = addrID;
    this.site = new Site(site.getEID(), site.getSID());
}
```

and getters and setters also

So for Site class i use follow serialize class

```
public class SiteSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Site>  {
@Override
public void serialize(Site obj, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                      SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
{
    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
    jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("sID");
    jsonGenerator.writeNumber(obj.getSID());
    jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("eID");
    jsonGenerator.writeString(obj.getEID());
    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
}
```

then I want to serialize my Address class. For this I can do following:

```
   public class AddressUnitSerializer extends JsonSerializer<AddressUnitPOJO> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(AddressUnitPOJO obj, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                          SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
                                        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();

        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("addressID");
        jsonGenerator.writeNumber(obj.getAddressID());

//I don't want to do this rutine every time!!!
/*      jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("Site");

        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("sID");
        jsonGenerator.writeNumber(obj.getSite().getSID());
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("eID");
        jsonGenerator.writeNumber(obj.getSite().getEID());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();*/
//!!!

        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();

    }
}
```

How I can reuse my previos serialization of child object? I searched for answers, but didn't find solution.
Thanks in advice!

**Edit 1**

So what I do now is

```
  public class AddressUnitSerializer extends JsonSerializer<AddressUnitPOJO> {

@Override
public void serialize(AddressUnitPOJO obj, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                      SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
                                    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();

    jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("addressID");
    jsonGenerator.writeNumber(obj.getAddressID());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(JsonMethod.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_NULL_PROPERTIES, false);
Site site = obj.getAddressUnit().getSite();

jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("Site");
jsonGenerator.writeString(mapper.writeValueAsString(site).
                            substring(0,mapper.writeValueAsString(site).length()-1));


    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();

}
 }
```

But maybe there is better way to convert this with annotations?

Comment: Why are you using a custom serializer for your address object? It doesn't appear to need any special handling. Or is this a simplified, more general question on how to invoke default serialization within a custom serializer?

Comment: Excuse me, I'm not a master in JSON, it just my variant of realization. If your know better way could your give me some links, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest way to generate JSON String is to use 
method `.writeObject(objName)`, which autogenerate fields and their values.
If you need other name of values or exclude values from generation or format string, than you can use standart declaration.